# Scraping infinite scrolling table data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to ask how to scrape table data at this website https://gis.dukcapil.kemendagri.go.id/peta/ using python?

Data at this table:

[image: data at this table]

Comment: OK, and what is your code? What did you try until now?

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the network tab in your browser tools. You will see the data is being population via `rest api call.` In such cases, you can directly make the api call to get the data. There is no need to extract data from the table.

For this particular website, this is api call that is loading the entire data in the table.

```
https://gis.dukcapil.kemendagri.go.id/arcgis/rest/services/Data_Baru_26092017/MapServer/3/q[…]rsects&outFields=*&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=25
```

Happy Scraping :)